# How to translate a pyomo constraint to an rule expression?

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo

I am learning pyomo and working with a toy example, more specifically I would like to understand how to build an expression constraint rule with Pyomo and ultimately convert them into a decorator form - I have the following model that is working and produce the expected output.

```
from pyomo.environ import *

L = {"s": 3, "j": 5, "f": 8}
B = {"s": 2, "j": 5, "f": 8}
C = {"s": 2, "j": 3, "f": 4}
P = {"s": 3, "j": 5, "f": 7}

limit_b = 325
limit_l = 400

model = ConcreteModel()

model.PACKAGES = Set(initialize=L.keys())

model.x = Var(model.PACKAGES, within=NonNegativeIntegers)

model.value = Objective(
    expr=sum((P[i] - C[i]) * model.x[i] for i in model.PACKAGES), sense=maximize
)

model.L_cst = Constraint(
    expr=sum(L[i] * model.x[i] for i in model.PACKAGES) <= limit_l
)

model.ballon_cst = Constraint(
    expr=sum(B[i] * model.x[i] for i in model.PACKAGES) <= limit_b
)

opt = SolverFactory("cbc")
results = opt.solve(model, tee=True)
model.pprint()
print("Objective value:", model.value())
```

From this code, I would like to use expressions and pyomo `Sets` however I cannot convert the code in the correct way.

```
from pyomo.environ import *

model = ConcreteModel(name="Profit")

# Define sets
model.k = Set(initialize=["s", "j", "f"], doc="Types of package")
model.b = Set(initialize=[2, 5, 8], doc="B")
model.l = Set(initialize=[3, 5, 8], doc="L")
model.c = Set(initialize=[2, 3, 4], doc="C")
model.p = Set(initialize=[3, 5, 7], doc="P")


limit_B = 325
limit_L = 400

model.x = Var(model.k, within=NonNegativeIntegers)


def obj_rule(model):
    return sum((model.p[i] - model.c[i]) * model.x[i] for i in model.k)


model.object = Objective(rule=obj_rule, sense=maximize)


def max_L_per_month_rule(model):
    return sum(model.l[i] * model.x[i] for i in model.k) <= limit_L


model.max_L_per_month = Constraint(model, rule=max_L_per_month_rule)


def max_B_per_month_rule(model):
    return sum(model.b[i] * model.x[i] for i in model.k) <= limit_B


model.max_B_per_month = Constraint(
    model, rule=max_B_per_month_rule
)

opt = SolverFactory("cbc")
results = opt.solve(model, tee=True)
model.pprint()
print("Objective value:", model.value())
```

Can someone help me and explain the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your constraints is that you are passing the model as the first argument. Positional arguments in `Constraint` components are assumed to be indexing sets. Your constraint is not indexed so the correct way to declare it using a rule would be:

```
model.max_L_per_month = Constraint(rule=max_L_per_month_rule)
```

I recommend taking a look at the [online documentation](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pyomo_modeling_components/Constraints.html) for examples of declaring constraints using rules and the [Pyomo workshop slides](https://software.sandia.gov/downloads/pub/pyomo/Pyomo-Workshop-Summer-2018.pdf) for an overview on the decorator notation